# Google Analytics Data Retention Policy - Bulk Changes?

Tags: google-analytics

With Google Analytics New Data Retention Changes. Are there any ways to implement it to all accounts under your main log in? We have multiple accounts. If anyone could help it'd be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much. Reference article on the Policy: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7667196

Answer (score 0):

Updating this setting in batch is unfortunately not possible. You have to click your way through the interface for each property one by one.

These data retention settings can be updated via the [GA management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties#resource), but write requests have a daily quota of 50.